# Can not log in to Laravel API via NextJs even though it's working with Postman

Tags: laravel, next.js, laravel-sanctum

I am now creating a backend with Laravel and frontend with NextJs. I am using Laravel Sanctum to authenticate users via API. I have set up required things on Laravel and tested using Postman. It's working fine on Postman (It issues the user a token with cookie) but I keep receiving this error on NextJs POST http://localhost:8000/api/login 419 (unknown status) and can not proceed.

Auth Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        if (!Auth::attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))) {
            return response([
                'message' => 'Invalid Response',
            ], Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
        }

        $user = Auth::user();

        $token = $user->createToken('token')->plainTextToken;

        $cookie = cookie('jwt', $token, 60 * 24);

        return response(['message' => 'Success', 'token' => $token])->withCookie($cookie);
    }

    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $cookie = Cookie::forget('jwt');

        return response(['message' => 'Logged out successfully!'])->withCookie($cookie);
    }
}
```

Routes (routes/api/admin.php)

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\API\UserController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::post('register', [App\Http\Controllers\API\AuthController::class, 'register']);
Route::post('login', [App\Http\Controllers\API\AuthController::class, 'login']);

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
    Route::apiResource('users', UserController::class)->parameters(['users' => 'user_code']);

    Route::post('logout', [App\Http\Controllers\API\AuthController::class, 'logout']);
});
```

Http/Middleware/authenticate.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (!$request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('login');
        }
    }

    public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        if ($jwt = $request->cookie('jwt')) {
            $request->headers->set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $jwt);
        }

        $this->authenticate($request, $guards);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

This is how I am trying to login in NextJs

```
await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/login', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  //   credentials: 'include',
  body: JSON.stringify({
     email: values.email,
     password: values.password,
  }),
});
```

Comment: not sure why it's working in postman but you don't seem to be sending the CSRF token here

Comment: I watched this tutorial from YouTube `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jIzPuM76-nI&list=PLlameCF3cMEsbPs3bmm98UP3Ny8tqNs1f&index=1` and it's working fine there. Even Nextjs application is working in its another part `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gum76LQcJXY&list=PLlameCF3cMEsbPs3bmm98UP3Ny8tqNs1f&index=2`. I actually followed the same but not working for me.

Comment: Where are you making the fetch request from? Client-side inside a `useEffect`, or server-side inside `getServerSideProps`/`getStaticProps`/API route?